# Windows 10 FIle query issues

Tags: c#, windows-phone, windows-phone-8.1, windows-8.1, windows-10

I am trying to follow the instructions to get files from the knownfolders in windows 10 as shown below,

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/br227275.aspx

```
            try
            {
                StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
                IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> pics = await folder.GetFilesAsync(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate, 0, 20);
                Debug.WriteLine(pics.Count);
            }

            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            }
```

The same code works in WindowsPhone 8.1 SDK. But on Windows 10 mobile it does not. The exception i get is this,

> The specified query options are not available for this folder because
>   it is not within a library or Homegroup. Only folders within a library
>   or a Homegroup support all options.

Any Ideas as to how to fix this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Windows 10 is still under work. The latest build on the phone resolved this issue.

Comment: Indeed, found a couple of issues like this so good to know things like this are being resolved

Answer (score -1):

Windows 10 mobile is the same for Windows 10 desktop. example code from MSDN:

Try using the code you have without a try catch block. Also, be aware that this is using asynchronous programming techniques.

Comment: Your answer was highly irrelevant. Please do not answer if you do not know.Thanks.

Answer (score -1):

You need to give Capability of Pictures Library to access pictures and relate info from it.

**Go in Solution Explorer of your app >> then "Package.appxmanifest" >> then "Capabilities" >> Select "Pictures Library" (if its not selected then select it).**

After it rebuild your project you can able to run your code successfully.
Hope this help You :-)

Answer (score -1):

Updated the answer, below code works, tested it

```
StorageFolder folder = KnownFolders.PicturesLibrary;
StorageFileQueryResult query = folder.CreateFileQuery(Windows.Storage.Search.CommonFileQuery.OrderByDate);
IReadOnlyList<StorageFile> pics = await query.GetFilesAsync(0, 20);
Debug.WriteLine(pics.Count);
```

there is an example to get folder queries on MSDN, applied the same to file queries 
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/xaml/jj150593.ASP